# How to choose WatchKit App's parent target?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parent, target, watchkit

I have an iOS application with **several** targets, which runs in a really different way on each of them. I added a watchkit app to it, but haven't found a way to **specify which target of my app should be the parent**. Have any of you found a way? Or is it something to ask Apple about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do this. You can set the target when you create the WatchKit App. Here are the steps:

- Set up all your targets in your project (I believe you have this completed)
- Select the + under targets and create a new `WatchKit App`
- The next options page let's you pick from a bunch of options to set up the WatchKit App target
- Under `Embed in Application`, choose the target you want to embed the WatchKit App in

I just confirmed this on Xcode 6.2 Beta 5.

Comment: That's awesome man, thank you. I've been looking all around with my WatchKit target already created, but I think the only way is to set it when you create the target, as you said.

Comment: Is there any way to embed watch kit in more than one target in the single project ?